# Error loading il8n console in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to generate the .po files for the site I'm working with. When I run this command from within the console directory:

```
Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PDT/-7.0/DST' instead in /Users/bkelly/Development/[redacted]/www/trunk/about/trunk/cake/libs/cache.php on line 570

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PDT/-7.0/DST' instead in /Users/bkelly/Development/[redacted]/www/trunk/about/trunk/cake/libs/cache.php on line 570

Error: Class Il8nShell could not be loaded.
```

This also happens if I issue  `./cake il8n help` . The `bake` console seems to load fine (no errors, takes me to the expected menu). I'm running CakePHP 1.3.0 under Mac OSX 10.6 (using MAMP). Cake appears to be functioning normally otherwise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because it's called **i18n** (*ai-eighteen-enn*), not il8n (*ai-ell-eight-enn*). :)

It may help to know that this is a [numeronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym) of *internationalization*, replacing the middle *18 characters* with "18". L10n stands for *localization*.